# Regular Expression Replace, can't insert simple character

Tags: regex, coda

I have tried everything possible and 2 hours trying to get this to work.

I'm using the search and replace option in Code (version 1) but just can't get the replace code working.

I want to add a semi colon in between some characters. I search like this:

```
)}[a-z]
```

..and that works fine.

and I've tried all of these, but not one keeps the [a-z] part, they all remove/replace it.

```
)};\1
)};*1
)};[a-z]
)};\1\2
)};$1
)};($1)
)};(\1)
)};[$1]
)};[\1]
```

I've set it to use the POSIX Basic option, but any option, setting will do. I just need it to simply insert a semicolon

Comment: What language? It can make a difference.

Comment: I haven't a clue. I'm using it in Coda (version 1) using POSIX Basic. Is that a language? Thanks for the help

Comment: The problem is that you forgot the parentheses around `[a-z]` in your search. It needs to be a numbered group.

Comment: OK, that will help. I took the liberty of adding a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
s/\)\}([a-z])/)};\1/g
```

In essence, we literally match a close parenthesis followed by a close brace. We then match a letter between `a` and `z`, but the parentheses around the `[a-z]` make that a capture group that we can reference. We can then (and only then) use `\1` in the replacement. Without a capture group, it doesn't know what `\1` refers to. With one, it does.

Using it with `sed`:

```
% echo 'hello)}world' | sed -Ee 's/\)\}([a-z])/)};\1/g'
hello)};world
```